# Alternatives for java reflection?

Tags: java

I just ran across errors about not finding Executable or Parameters from java.lang.reflect. Is there a working equivalent for Java 1.6

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2014/04/01/jdk-compatibility.html) might be relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, both `Executable` and `Parameter` were added to the (JDK) reflection API in Java 8.